# Append one column table to another existing, larger table SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table name KHA_ID with a column name of KHA_ID.  I went to append that to another table named Visits with a column name KHA_ID, and I want to see if I have my SQL right before I run the query

```
INSERT INTO [databaseName].[dbo].[KHA_ID]
(KHA_ID)
VALUES (KHA_ID,[dbo].Visits)

GO
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO [databaseName].[dbo].[KHA_ID]
(KHA_ID)
SELECT KHA_ID
FROM [dbo].Visits
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

If KHA_ID is the primary key in KHA_ID table then

```
INSERT INTO [databaseName].[dbo].[KHA_ID]
(KHA_ID)
SELECT distinct KHA_ID
FROM [dbo].Visits V left outer join 
KHA_ID from [databaseName].[dbo].[KHA_ID] K on K.KHA_ID=V.KHA_ID 
where K.KHA_ID is null
GO
```